# What is the correct method to destroy a jqGrid to avoid detached DOM nodes?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm currently facing a situation where I need to destroy a jqGrid that holds a large number of rows before creating a new set of DOM elements. I've tried using jqGrid's GridDestroy method, but it is still leaving a large number of detached DOM nodes so I thought I might be doing it incorrectly.

Here is my current process that is still leaving detached DOM nodes:

```
$(deleteButton).click(function () {
    $('#grid').jqGrid("clearGridData");
    $('#grid').jqGrid('GridDestroy');
    $('#grid').remove();
    $('#gridContainer').empty();
});
```

I felt like this process was overkill, but it is still resulting in detached DOM nodes. I've set up an example in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8DYD8/1/).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the create button to create the jqGrid
2. Click the delete button
3. Take a heap snapshot using Chrome's debugger->Profiles tab, and you should see numerous detached DOM nodes in the snapshot

[image: Detached DOM nodes due to jqGrid]

Comment: I've noticed upgrading the jQuery framework from 1.6.4 to 2.1.0 seems to help. However, it does still leak occasionally so not an idea solution.

Answer (score -1):

According to jqgrid expert @oleg:

> The method GridDestroy works like jQuery.remove. It deletes all
>   elements which belong to the grid inclusve the  element.
>
> The method GridUnload on the other hand delete all, but the empty
>    element stay on the page. So you are able to create new grid
>   on the same place.

According to the jqGrid wiki:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

**GridDestroy** is what you need:

> Destroys the entry grid with id= grid_id from the DOM (clears all the
>   html associated with the grid and unbinds all events)

Comment: As you can see from the question and the jsFiddle I am using 'GridDestroy'

Comment: Its clearly mentioned in the question that OP is already using GridDestroy